# Next js middleware session

Tags: next.js, hook

I have this part of my code:

`const token = useAppSelector((state)=>state.UserLogged.userLogged.token)`

this line is for get token is one user is logged, so, que I run and I press `ctrl + f5` on mapge `dashboard` or `profile` I get this issue: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')`

look this photo

[image]

so, is like don't found the hook, what's wrong??

Comment: `useAppSelector` is a hook. hooks only can be called inside client react components